# Wordpress Plugins Not Installing (Ubuntu, Ssh2)

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, ubuntu, ssh

I'm running an ubuntu server with apache, and I have wordpress all installed. We're trying to get the themes and plugins available for install through the wp-admin console. So **I used this guide to implement SSH2 instead of FTP.**

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-secure-updates-and-installations-in-wordpress-on-ubuntu

So everything finally works for installing themes. I'm assuming when I'm uploading the zip and that's getting installed that it's correctly using the ssh settings.

However, **when trying to install a plugin I'm redirected to** :
http://ServerIpAddress/wp-admin/themes.php?page=tgmpa-install-plugins

That just gives me a ***"No data received"*** Chrome Page.

So the guide had me mess around with a bunch of permissions, but this almost seems kind of far removed from the ssh. The ssh is working for themes. It's not spitting out the same errors it used to when ssh wasn't implemented properly. So I figure this is something new. Has anyone seen this

Comment: The argument in the url you are redirected to is for the plugin called 
TGM Plugin Activation which allows developers to install and even automatically activate plugins from their themes and plugins. Seems like this plugin is not installed correctly or has some issues. Turning on debug_mode and checking the errors might help shred some light.

Comment: +1 for debug, thank you. Isn't TGM pretty core though? It's automatic for me when I select "Begin Installing Plugins" from the plugins menu, where it says "This theme recommends the following plugins: ...." That link just takes me to the tgm page immediately

Comment: Nope, TGM is an external plugin (actually, a PHP library wrapped as a plugin) and has nothing to do with WordPress core. Many premium themes use it to install and activate required plugins right after theme activation. You should probably look for a TGM support forum and ask there as well, if debugging will not help.

Comment: Ok I get it. But I get the same behavior using the normal wordpress plugin browser. Instead it redirects to this, but still no data received: http://IP.IP.IP/wp-admin/update.php?action=install-plugin&plugin=akismet&_wpnonce=405f39b360

Comment: I've done some googling on 'No data received' message, seems like it's not actually a WP issue, rather hosting. As far as I understand, you are on a VPS and you've configured everything by yourself. Possible problems: 1. Permissions and file ownership; 2. Low PHP memory limit. Try increasing PHP memory limit, if it does not help - review files/dirs ownership and permissions.